# How do I iterate over a list in order of the amounts of 1's in the binary value of the index? (Python preferably)

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic, binary

If I have a huge list (like 2^50 elements), how do I iterate over this list, but in order of the number of 1's in the binary value of the index, in the fastest way possible in Python?

So for example first 11111111, then 11111110, 11111101, 11111011, 11110111, 11101111, 11011111, 10111111, 01111111, then 11111100 etc.

The reason I need this is because I am doing dynamic programming to find a value for each subset of a given set V, denoted with value(subset) and because there are so many possible subsets I decided to denote the subsets in binary, so that the subset {v1,v2,v5} is 000010011 for example. I have to iterate in the mentioned order because the recursive function I have to use has the base case value(V)=0, i.e. value(1111111111111)=0, and builds further with decreasing size in subset, i.e. the amount of 1's in the binary value.

If there is completely different approach not using binary at all, please let me know! Thnank you so much for reading this,
Joost

**EDIT:** this is the recursive function:
[image: recursive function], where N(v) is the neighbors of vertex v. (It's a graph problem).
pseudo code would look like this, for a set V and subsets X:

```
value(V)=0
Forloop in described order:
    pick a vertex v from V that is not in X and denote it in binary
    subset, so that for example  v = 001000000, where X = 010111101
    #Use bitwise operator '|' to get intersections of binary values: 
    value(X) = value(X|v) + value(X|N(v)) + 1
```

PS: You can just use normal integers in python and the bitwise operator will still work: 8|4 will return 12: 100|010 = 110

Comment: How have you attempted this, please show some code?

Comment: I dont have any code yet, because I wouldn't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two separate approaches are proposed below.

#### Approach 1: Generator based on Combinations

One way to implement this is with an outer loop over the number of on-bits, and an inner loop over the positions of on-bits. For the inner loop, a [combination generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Enumerating_k-combinations) can be used to iterate over the positions of on-bits. The corresponding sequence would start with the number with all on-bits, followed by numbers with all but one on-bit, followed by numbers with all but two on-bits, ..., and finally end with 0 (no on-bits). A combination of on-bit positions can be converted to a number by summing `2^position` across the positions of on-bits.

For the question's use case, the elements of the sequence would be used as indices for traversing over the relevant list.

Revolving door combination generators iterate over small sets of items to be swapped in and out of a combination on each visit. Such an algorithm could possibly be used to reduce the computational requirements of the approach proposed above, by modifying the current number on each iteration based on which bit will be turned on and which bit will be turned off.

Here's an implementation in Python that does not use a revolving door approach, based on Python's built-in `itertools.combinations`. The example usage below the function uses eight total bits. For each of the numbers in the generated sequence, the output shows 1) the decimal representation, 2) the binary representation, and 3) the count of on-bits.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def generator(num_bits):
    powers = [2 ** exponent for exponent in range(num_bits - 1, -1, -1)]
    for num_on in range(num_bits, -1, -1):
        for positions in combinations(range(num_bits), num_on):
            yield sum(powers[position] for position in positions)

for x in generator(8):
    binary = f'{x:#010b}'
    bit_count = binary.count('1')
    print(f'{x:03} {binary} {bit_count}')
```

Output:

```
255 0b11111111 8
254 0b11111110 7
253 0b11111101 7
251 0b11111011 7
247 0b11110111 7
239 0b11101111 7
223 0b11011111 7
191 0b10111111 7
127 0b01111111 7
252 0b11111100 6
250 0b11111010 6
249 0b11111001 6
...
006 0b00000110 2
005 0b00000101 2
003 0b00000011 2
128 0b10000000 1
064 0b01000000 1
032 0b00100000 1
016 0b00010000 1
008 0b00001000 1
004 0b00000100 1
002 0b00000010 1
001 0b00000001 1
000 0b00000000 0
```

#### Approach 2: Ordered List of Indices

An alternative approach—using more memory than the prior method—is to calculate the number of on-bits in each number (where "number" here is an index), and then create a list of numbers in descending order of their number of on-bits.

Here's an implementation in Python. For the letters from `a` to `z`, the output shows the characters ordered by the number of bits in their index, along with each character's index, its binary representation, and the count of on-bits. `bin(.).count('1')` is used for counting the number of on-its in each number. [Issue 29882](https://bugs.python.org/issue29882) on [bugs.python.org](https://bugs.python.org) suggests that a built-in `bit_count` method will be available in Python 3.10.

```
letters = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
]

n = len(letters)
bit_counts = [bin(x).count('1') for x in range(n)]
indices_lookup = [[] for _ in range(len(bin(n)) - 2)]
for idx, bit_count in enumerate(bit_counts):
    indices_lookup[bit_count].append(idx)
ordered_indices = []
for idxs in reversed(indices_lookup):
    ordered_indices.extend(idxs)

for x in ordered_indices:
    print(f'{letters[x]} {x:02} {x:#07b}')
```

Output:

```
p 15 0b01111 4
x 23 0b10111 4
h 07 0b00111 3
l 11 0b01011 3
n 13 0b01101 3
o 14 0b01110 3
t 19 0b10011 3
v 21 0b10101 3
w 22 0b10110 3
z 25 0b11001 3
d 03 0b00011 2
f 05 0b00101 2
g 06 0b00110 2
j 09 0b01001 2
k 10 0b01010 2
m 12 0b01100 2
r 17 0b10001 2
s 18 0b10010 2
u 20 0b10100 2
y 24 0b11000 2
b 01 0b00001 1
c 02 0b00010 1
e 04 0b00100 1
i 08 0b01000 1
q 16 0b10000 1
a 00 0b00000 0
```

Comment: I implemented the first method and it works like a charm, thank you